# Animation Warning - Sending onAnimatedValueUpdate with no listeners registered (Material Top Tab)

Tags: reactjs, native

Tab.jsx

```
import { View, Text, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs";
import Ionic from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

const BottomTabView = () => {
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;

  let posts: JSX.Element[] = [];
  let numberOfposts = 7;

  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfposts; index++) {
    posts.push(
      <View key={index}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: screenWidth * 0.33,
            height: screenWidth * 0.33,
            marginVertical: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 0.1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  let reels: JSX.Element[] = [];
  let numberOfreels = 7;

  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfreels; index++) {
    reels.push(
      <View key={index}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: screenWidth * 0.33,
            height: screenWidth * 0.5,
            marginVertical: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 0.1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  let guides: JSX.Element[] = [];
  let numberOfguides = 7;

  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfguides; index++) {
    guides.push(
      <View key={index}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: screenWidth * 0.42,
            height: screenWidth * 0.6,
            marginVertical: 0.5,
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 0.1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  let effects: JSX.Element[] = [];
  let numberOfeffects = 7;

  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfeffects; index++) {
    effects.push(
      <View key={index}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: screenWidth * 0.49,
            height: screenWidth * 0.6,
            marginVertical: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 0.1,
          }}
        ></View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const Posts = () => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {posts}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

  const Reels = () => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {reels}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

  const Guide = () => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            padding: 20,
            rowGap: 20,
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {guides}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

  const Effects = () => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            padding: 2,
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {effects}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

  const Tags = () => {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
          }}
        >
          {posts}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarIndicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "black",
          height: 1.5,
        },
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === "Posts") {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-apps-sharp" : "ios-apps-sharp";
            color = focused ? "black" : "gray";
          } else if (route.name === "Reels") {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-play-circle" : "ios-play-circle-outline";
            color = focused ? "black" : "gray";
          } else if (route.name === "Guide") {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-book" : "ios-book-outline";
            color = focused ? "black" : "gray";
          } else if (route.name === "Effects") {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-color-wand" : "ios-color-wand-outline";
            color = focused ? "black" : "gray";
          } else if (route.name === "Tags") {
            iconName = focused ? "ios-person" : "ios-person-outline";
            color = focused ? "black" : "gray";
          }

          return <Ionic name={iconName || ""} color={"black"} size={22} />;
        },
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Posts" component={Posts} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Reels" component={Reels} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Guide" component={Guide} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Effects" component={Effects} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tags" component={Tags} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabView;
```

App.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Login from "./src/screens/Login";
import { User, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { FIREBASE_AUTH } from "./FirebaseConfig";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import ComingSoon from "./src/screens/ComingSoon";
import Profile from "./src/screens/Profile";
import Ionic from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import MaterialCommuniuty from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import Foundation from "react-native-vector-icons/Foundation";
import Feather from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function AfterLogin() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Foundation name="home" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Search"
          component={ComingSoon}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Feather name="search" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Create Post"
          component={ComingSoon}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <MaterialCommuniuty name="plus-box" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Reels"
          component={ComingSoon}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Foundation name="play-video" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Profile"
          component={Profile}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            tabBarLabel: () => null,
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <Ionic name="ios-person" color={color} size={size} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="LoggedIn"
            component={AfterLogin}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={Login}
            options={{ headerShown: false }}
          />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Everytime, I swipe on the Material Top Tab too fast or go left and right on the very edge/last tabs, I get the onAnimatedValueUpdate with no listeners registered warning. How do I go about fixing this. Thank you.

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7839
[WARN Sending `onAnimatedValueUpdate` with no listeners registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76012269/warn-sending-onanimatedvalueupdate-with-no-listeners-registered)
https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view/issues/1258

Tried all these discussions, but none of them really helped.

Comment: Hey @linuxman00, did you find a solution for this except ignoring it with LogBox? I also get the issue with swiping back to the previous screen.